# CSS - Set overall width of table when columns have manual set widths

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need a table with a sticky header that also scrolls left to right at smaller screen sizes.

I think this is the best way to do it with thead and tbody set the `display: block;` and `overflow-y: scroll;` on the tbody.

The problem with this is I have to set the widths of all the th and td and I also have the set the width of table.

Setting the widths of the th and td is fine but setting a width on the table means I could have space after the table on the right unless I work out the width of the table with the set widths of the columns.

```css
body {
  background: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.page {
  background: white;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.table-con {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
}

thead th,
tbody td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 1500px;
}

thead th:first-child {
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

thead {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}

thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) td:not(:first-child) {
  background: yellow;
}

tbody td:first-child {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

th:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(1) {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  width: 20px;
}

th:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 90px;
}

th:nth-child(3),
td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 200px;
}

th:nth-child(4),
td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 90px;
}

th:nth-child(5),
td:nth-child(5) {
  width: 90px;
}

th:nth-child(6),
td:nth-child(6) {
  width: 90px;
}

th:nth-child(7),
td:nth-child(7) {
  width: 90px;
}

th:nth-child(8),
td:nth-child(8) {
  width: 90px;
}

th:nth-child(9),
td:nth-child(9) {
  width: 100px;
}

th:nth-child(10),
td:nth-child(10) {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="table-con" id="table">
    <!--     <div class="white-block"></div>
    <div class="white-block white-block-1"></div> -->
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
          <th>Header 4</th>
          <th>Header 5</th>
          <th>Header 6</th>
          <th>Header 7</th>
          <th>Header 8</th>
          <th>Header 9</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256 Data - 1256 Data - 1256</td>
          <td>Data - 1256</td>
          <td>1256</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>Data - abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>abc</td>
          <td>ABCDE</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you don't want the table to have a set width?

Comment: Why are you setting the table to `display: block`? That is making it really screwy.

Comment: And what's up with the empty `th` in the `thead`?

Comment: I setting it to display block so I can make the header sticky